# Как хранить компоненты в строках? (Форматированные статьи с изображениями)

Tags: react-native

Есть большое количество (700) статей, содержащие форматированный текст (курсив, другой цвет итд) и картинки. По клику на элемент списка должна показываться статья.

Как лучше их хранить и восстанавливать? Уже пару дней думаю...

Comment: может это подойдет? https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md